# WebSocket connection cannot be made - Spark Java Framework

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, slf4j, spark-java

I've tried to recreate WebSocket chat app (http://sparkjava.com/tutorials/websocket-chat) in Spark Java framework and stumbled upon a problem.

Frontend app couldn't connect to the server via WebSocket. I've looked into "Network" tab in the browser and there's a proper WebSocket call to a server but it respond with **500 code**. There's no log on the server side, even though I've added *System.out.println* into *@OnWebSocketConnect* and *@OnWebSocketClose* functions. Why is that?

On every app launch I have an warning that says:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.... for further details.

I don't think this is the issue but it might be worth mentioning.

I've added an exception catcher to the main class too, but it doesn't fire up:

```
exception(Exception.class, (e, req, res) -> {
    System.err.println("Exception happened");
    e.printStackTrace();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. The problem was trivial: My *ChatWebSocketHandler* had incorrect implementation of *@OnWebSocketClosed* which was

```
public void onDisconnect(Session user)
```

instead of

```
public void onDisconnect(Session user, int statusCode, String reason).
```

Of course, proper Exception was thrown but mine invalid configuration of SLF4J made it quiet (NOP).

I've fixed the issue, and learned that I need to add dependencies below

```
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13"
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21"
```

to my gradle file to make SLF4J work properly.